# Dryer wiring is messed up i think

Tags: electrical, wiring

I'm having issues with dryer I took apart the outlet it's only three prong when I take my multimeter and touch the neutral to the negative I get no power I touch the neutral to the positive I get no power I touched the hot and the negative I get my 240 is that okay or is there something wrong in my wiring

Comment: Please upload a picture. There is no positive or negative with AC. You *should* have 4 wires - bare or green ground, white neutral, black and red (usually, colors can vary) hot. The hots should be 240V to each other, 120V to ground or neutral. The ground and neutral should be 0V to each other. A 3-prong receptacle should have hots and neutral but no ground.

Comment: Reading again, it sounds like your problem is a bad/broken neutral. Depending on configuration, that could be at the receptacle, at the panel or at some junction (wire nut or other splice) in between.

Comment: It sounds like your neutral is not connected anymore.  This also means there is no ground path to save you from electric shock.  Turn off the breaker for the dryer now.  Do not use.  Google nema type 10 circuits to see why they were banned.  You can repair that circuit, but it is highly recommended to upgrade to nema 14(hot, hot, neutral and ground).

Comment: I don't know too much on electricity just a little what do I have to do to fix that issue if that's what it is and thank you

Comment: How do I upload a picture to this page

Comment: I would suggest asking an electrician to do the work for your safety.  If you do want to fix it yourself, turn off the breaker for the dryer and/or the main breaker.  Check the outlet for loose connections(a wire loose).  If not there it might be in the panel, main breaker off for this part.

Comment: Is my bare wire and my white wire supposed to be connected to the same thing in my outlet

Comment: Please [edit] your question, then click the "sun & mountain" icon to upload a picture. Or, just drag the picture into the text edit box. Either way, the site will upload the image and host it for you. If you do have 4 wires - bare, white, red, black - then you're ideally suited for safety and modern code compliance. Before you do anything else, though, make sure the breaker is OFF and get the pic uploaded. That will help us help you.

Comment: The white wire is being used as the second hot(should have a black mark on it).  The bare is your neutral, it goes to the middle bottom/top slot.  the white to one side and the black to the other side.

Comment: You using Negative and positive is scary. Hope you survive long enough to continue this discussion.

Comment: So if I'm reading the comment right the red and black wire are my hots and then my white wire and my bare wire or my neutrals with the way this is set up is the red and black on my heart and then the white wire and bare wire are connected together as a neutral so when I put my multitester on my neutral and then on either one of the hots it shows no voltage or if I touch both of my hot I got 240 is that ok

Comment: It won't load up the picture

Comment: Most likely problem with the picture is that is larger than the truly arbitrary 2 Meg. limit. Which StackExchange should have fixed years ago by allowing a much larger size and automatically shrinking. But I digress.

Answer (score 3):

There is some good news here. Based on the comments, OP has black, red, white and bare. Which means this is a NEMA 10 that can be replaced with a NEMA 14, *provided the wires are all functioning properly*.

There are two likely possibilities here:

- Receptacle gone bad. That happens. Which is OK because we want you to replace it anyway.
- Neutral wire *someplace else* gone bad. That could be at a junction box in between the receptacle and the breaker panel or actually in the breaker panel. Or (small but non-zero possibility) rat chewed through wires somewhere.

So which is it? And what to do next?

- **Turn off the breaker**
- Disconnect all 4 wires from the receptacle and toss the receptacle. Yes, toss it. You don't want anyone else taking it and using it, plus even brand new and 100% working it is only worth $10 retail.
- Spread the 4 wires apart from each other and from the box (especially if the box is metal.
- Turn on the breaker.
- Carefully test the voltage between every pair of wires. Write the information down.
- Turn off the breaker.

If you get:

- Black - Red = 240V
- Black - White = 120V
- Red - White = 120V
- Black - bare = 120V
- Red - bare = 120V
- White - bare = 0V

then you are ready for step 2. If any reading is different from the above by more than a few volts, **STOP** and ask for more help.

The next step is to get a UL/ETL listed NEMA 14-30 receptacle, such as [this Leviton one from Amazon](https://amzn.to/3R1grgM):

[image: Leviton 14-30 receptacle]

Picture is from Amazon. Be extremely careful buying anything electrical from Amazon. Leviton is a good brand and Amazon makes it easy to import pictures to this site. But Amazon *also* sells a lot of not-UL-listed junk. For anything electrical, if it says "Shipped by Amazon" but "Sold by *someone else*" don't get it. The safest thing is to go to your local hardware store or Home Depot or Lowes or similar because they don't (or rarely, hopefully) sell unlisted stuff because the rules are a little different for bricks 'n mortar stores.

Connect it according to the instructions and then turn on the breaker and verify voltages in the receptacle.

The last step is to replace the dryer cord with [something like this Whirlpool cord from Amazon](https://amzn.to/45S2pSW):

[image: Whirlpool dryer cord]

Note that brand does not matter - i.e., you can use a Whirlpool cord with a GE dryer or vice versa. But as with the receptacle, make sure it is UL or ETL listed and bricks 'n mortar may be a better bet than Amazon unless you watch carefully (when you order and when you receive the order!) to make sure you get the real deal.

The final step is to install the cord on your dryer. The process varies by model. But basically involves removing some part of the back of the dryer, then removing the old cord and attaching the new one, and then **remove the neutral-ground bond from the dryer**. That last step is critical to making the 4-wire cord/receptacle safer than the 3-wire cord/receptacle. The exact process for doing that varies by model/manufacturer. If you are not sure, find the model # and ask a question here.

Finally, I prefer to verify that the neutral/ground bond is disconnected. To do this, set your multimeter on resistance. You should get close to 0 Ohms (and a beep if your meter beeps on continuity) between the ground pin of the cord and the metal case of the dryer but infinite Ohms/no continuity between the neutral pin of the cord and the metal case.

Comment: I find it amusing how many times I'm writing a short answer when you're putting together a long one. Take my upvote.

Comment: @KMJ And how often have I started a long answer and then Harper shows up with a HUGE answer :-)

Comment: Right? Yours doesn't even have a link to a Technology Connections video in it. Clearly slacking.

Answer (score 0):

Please note: the instructions below might result in needing to go behind the cover / dead front on an electrical panel. Electrical work can be dangerous. If you are not confident of how to do it safely, please hire it out or at least do more reading in a DIY book. Full education on how to safely work with 240V is out of the scope of this answer.

Since you said in the comments that you have red, black, white, and bare wires, this means you have a four wire circuit. Here's the correct wiring at the receptacle end:

[image: Receptacle wiring]

If you have four wires but a three prong receptacle, it's wrong. To fix it you will need to replace the receptacle and the dryer cord. See your dryer installation manual for correct wiring instructions.

At the breaker panel end, the red and black wires are connected to the circuit breaker. The white wire will be under a screw at the neutral bus. The bare wire will be under a screw at the ground bus. If it's a subpanel, those will always be separate. In a main panel, they may be the same bus.

If you can't get 120v to either hot leg from ground or neutral, then your ground or neutral is open. This either means it's not properly connected at the panel end, or there is a break in the wire.

Comment: *The bare wire will be under a screw at the ground bus. If it's a subpanel, those will always be separate. In a main panel, they may be the same bus.* Mostly correct. But actually in a main panel it is 100% legitimate to have separate (but bonded) neutral and ground buses, and in that case grounds can go on the neutral bus but neutrals can't go on the ground bus. Better to keep separate (except for the bond) but not strictly necessary. When my electrician was doing my heavy-up, he put a few (but just a few) grounds on the neutral bar due to the layout of the panel and the short old wires.

Comment: I've seen more than a couple professionally installed and signed off main panels where grounds and neutrals are freely mixed across the bars, so this may be more of a 'code vs practice' thing. The important part I was trying to get the Asker to notice was that if you mix them in a subpanel, Bad Things can happen. Mixing them in a main panel is not the end of the world.

Comment: Agreed. Code says: Neutral on neutral, ground on neutral or ground. Best practices says neutral on neutral and ground on ground so that if you ever turn this main panel into a subpanel you don't have to move any ground wires. Wrong but not fatal says neutral, ground - they're bonded anyway in this box so "whatever". Wrong *and* fatal says: They're bonded in the main panel so I can mix them up elsewhere...